# Swift EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on Firebase Firestore call

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Edit: I figured out it has to do with "isLoading" and how that affects UI. Timing just made it seem like Firebase.**

I am uploading data to Firestore but am receiving a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` error at some point after the data is uploaded to Firestore but before the callback happens.

Post function is called on button click

```
func post(for user: User, onSuccess: @escaping() -> Void) {
    isLoading = true
    
    let post = Post(text: message, upvotes: [user.uid:true], upvoteCount: 1, downvoteCount: 0, postDate: Date().timeIntervalSince1970, ownerId: user.uid)
    API.Post.post(post, onSuccess: {
        self.isLoading = false
        onSuccess()
    }) { (errorString) in
        self.isLoading = false
        self.errorMessage = errorString
        self.showAlert = true
    }
}
```

It calls my PostAPI function

```
func post(_ post: Post, onSuccess: @escaping() -> Void, onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void) {
    let collection = FRef.FFirestore.FPosts.MY_POSTS_DOCUMENT_USERID(userId: post.ownerId).collection(FirebaseConstants.Firestore.USER_POSTS_COLLECTION)
    let postId = collection.document().documentID
    let firestorePostRef = collection.document(postId)
    
    guard let dict = try? post.toDictionary() else { return }
    
    firestorePostRef.setData(dict) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            onError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        onSuccess()
    }
}
```

This uploads the data successfully but never reaches the callback. If I put a breakpoint on the `if error != nil` line it is never hit even though the data is uploaded

Comment: There is too much going on behind the scenes that could be causing this problem. It appears you call a number of static or singleton objects throughout the post process, including one just to construct the Firestore collection. Personally, I'd greatly simplify this process which would make debugging these kinds of problems incredibly straightforward. Also, you have two completion handlers for a single function (one for success, one for failure); I'd avoid this pattern and have a single completion handler that returns perhaps a `Result` object.

Comment: It's not really that confusing as it is just a few constants being called. But I do agree that I can just make the creation of the document all in one line. This was left over from a separate call where I needed the id for storage. I will also clean up the completion handlers. Turns out it had to do with something unrelated to Firestore